# browser.driver.manage().window().maximize(); not working

Tags: protractor, cucumber

browser.driver.manage().window().maximize(); is not working in my file, it's giving the error- Type Error: Cannot read property 'manage' of undefined

```
onPrepare: function(){
browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
}
```

Comment: Do I need to install something in particular

Comment: try it without `driver`.  i.e. `browser.manage().window().maximize();`

Comment: What browser(s) are you using?

Comment: Used that also @Gunderson still having the same error.

Comment: I m using only chrome @BenMohorc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to maximize your window in the onPrepare function, you can set it inside chromeOptions in capabilities using the argument `'--window-size=1920,1080'` This assumes your maximum size is 1920x1080, and you could tweak it if you are on higher or lower resolution.
Example (conf.js):

```
capabilities:{
    browserName: 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
        args:['--window-size=1920,1080']
    }
}
```

This works with headless mode as well, although in headless you can choose whatever resolution you want, even if it is higher than your computers native resolution.